# Маркитантка

Tags: фонетика

Как это слово произносится?

*Задали такой вопрос - встал в тупик.
Правописание-то я могу посмотреть в словарях, но нигде нет помет об особенностях чтения.
Вместе с тем обилие примеров с неправильным написанием заставляет предположить, что как минимум половина пишущих делают это по слуху.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сочетаниях согласных нтк и ндк по нормам русской орфоэпии звук [т] - непроизносимый в нескольких иностранных словах, давно освоенных разговорной речью, например, в слове голландка (печь)-голла[нк]а. В других случаях согласный [т] произносится: лаборантка -лабора[нтк]а, студентка - студе[нтк]а, аспирантка - аспира[нтк]а, официантка -официа[нтк]а.

Я думаю, маркитантка не относится к словам, давно освоенным разговорной речью. Слово-то давнее, но произносят его редко, часто в исторических произведениях, в военной литературе. Поэтому согласный Т произносится чётко, чтобы соотнести его по смыслу со словом маркитант.

http://diktory.com/soch_sogl.html

Comment: Вообще-то я и в "голландке" Т произношу...
Ладно, спасибо.